# What Does the Batch Command rp Do?

Tags: batch-file, makefile

I have a makefile that is ran by GNU Make in Windows. There are two lines within a target's recipe that I did not write, these are them:

```
@echo Executing Command
@rp prebuild
```

I know what the `@` symbol does, it prevents the command from being echoed to the batch shell. Therefore the first line will not say:

```
echo Executing Command
Executing Command
```

Instead it will just say:

```
Executing Command
```

However what does the second line do? I can't seem to find any information for the rp command under the batch syntax.

Comment: `RP` is not an internal shell command or a Windows executable. Must be coming from some other program you have installed.

Comment: Check your build log, its output might show there.  Also remove the '@' symbol, run the build and observe.

Comment: try `rp /?` or `rp -h`, which might show you some helpful hints.

Comment: rp must be an external program installed. Can I know what the context is? It could be a virus. (sorry I originally posted this as an answer, I just got up...)

Comment: Thanks guys, you were right. Although it's not a virus, it was an external batch script named rp.bat that it was calling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was an external batch script named rp.bat that it was calling.